# Windows command line: how to make it so I can type "php" instead of "C:\php\php.exe"

Tags: windows, windows-11

How to make it so I can type "php" instead of "C:\php\php.exe" in Windows command line (and this persisting after I restart)?

I tried to set it as an environment variable but that didn't work. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: add `C:\php` to the PATH in  System Properties :: Advanced :: Environment Variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the windows search bar, enter `env`. Then open the app.
2. Click on the edit environment variables button (at the bottom)
3. Select the variable names `Path` and click on `edit`
4. Enter the path (`C:\php`) to the new line and save